# How to create object properties from a JS string

Tags: javascript, object

I have the following object

```
reportData: {}
```

and the following loop :

```
    for (var key in ABC.PrintReport.keyList) {
        console.log(ABC.PrintReport.keyList[key].Report_Key);
    }
```

This loop will print out :

```
objProperty0
objProperty1
objProperty2
objProperty3
```

I want to create properties for the object `reportData` that are named after each `ABC.PrintReport.keyList[key].Report_Key`.

```
reportData.objProperty0
reportData.objProperty1
reportData.objProperty2
reportData.objProperty3
```

Comment: Can you not use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation), like you do with `keyList` and `key`? So `reportData[objProperty0] = 'something';`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use square brackets to create properties on objects in JavaScript:

```
for (var key in ABC.PrintReport.keyList) {
    var k = ABC.PrintReport.keyList[key].Report_Key;
    reportData[k] = 'some value';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it (see docs on [bracket notation for object property access](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators)):

```
var reportData = {};
for (var key in ABC.PrintReport.keyList) {
    key = ABC.PrintReport.keyList[key].Report_Key;
    reportData[key] = 'some value';
}
```

Comment: This answer is just as good as the one I accepted. The only reason I didn't pick this one is because you overwrite `key` and it can no longer be used as an index.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var key in ABC.PrintReport.keyList) {
    reportData[ABC.PrintReport.keyList[key].Report_Key] = ABC.PrintReport.keyList[key].Report_Key;
}
```